# HTTP 413 Request Entity Too Large in Node JS Project in GAE

Tags: node.js, json, nginx, google-app-engine, body-parser

I have my backend app deployed on GAE. Inside it, I am having an API which will upload a file to a GCS bucket. 
Recently I tried uploading a file of more than 50mb size and got `413 Request entity too large`

Did some research and found out that the issue is with `ngnix`. The API  will give `413` for any file > 32Mb.

Found one solution where it was mentioned to include a `ngnix.conf` file and add `client_max_body_size  80M` in it.
I did so but still getting the same error.

This is my `ngnix-app.conf` file

```
server{
 location / {
        client_max_body_size       80m;
        client_body_buffer_size    512k;
  }
}
```

Anything obvious that I am missing out here?

Comment: You can try adding parameterLimit in your bodyParser

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ "limit": "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 1000000 }));

This worked for me.

Comment: You could also compress the file on the client and de-compress on the server.

Comment: @ChrisAdams actually the whole thing is happening in backend only. I have a schedule that takes backup of my database every night and then itself call the API to upload the backup SQL file in GCS bucket

Comment: Ah, yes, missed that in the Q,

Comment: Please check the second edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965089/3058302). You have to modify the maximum size in Node, like this: 

`app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));`
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));`

Comment: similar with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197856/node-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large-client-max-body-size-set/54140202#54140202

Answer (score 11):

You can change your request buffer size in your Node.Js application using

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'})); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

Also you can increase your request in nginx configuration

```
server{
 location / {
        client_max_body_size       xxm;
        client_body_buffer_size    xxm;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the answer for anyone coming across this kind of error in GAE with the NodeJs application. I've got HTTP 413 with a JSON payload of a few kilobytes, which is confusing and not mentioned anywhere in official docs. Make sure to include "body-parser" into your project/application as you don't need it by default and it is auto provided by the GAE environment.

Comment: using urlencoded doesn't work  for multipart/formdata

Comment: @PranuPranav What works for formdata ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Just Modify NGINX Configuration File

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
   ```
2. Search for this variable: **client_max_body_size**. If you find it, then just increase the value to 100M. If you can't find this then just add
   this line inside HTTP.

   ```
   client_max_body_size 100M;
   ```
3. To apply changes just restart ngnix

   ```
   sudo service nginx restart
   ```

See screenshot for better understand
[image]